# Difficulties in learning Objective-C. " error Expected Identifier " @interface. ( I am new to Obj-C )

Tags: objective-c

My Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}


@interface <# class name #> : <# superclass #>

@end
```

Comment: Not clear, you are showing placeholders. plz show real code, wht you wrote.

Comment: I am new to this programming language. Just started today. This is what I wrote and not more. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes for you:

• Make sure that file name has extension .m Or .mm

• In target->Build Settings-> Compile Sources As: According to File Type

I don't think SO is good place for you to ask this kind of simple question. You may get solution for this then ton's of similar eror you get in future.

So better learn Obj.C first in right place.

• https://developer.apple.com/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am learning Objective-C from today with the online tutorials which are 2 years old (from the newboston youtube channel) and when I type what is mentioned in the tutorials, it is showing lots of errors. :(

Answer (score -2):

just remove below code and try to build again (command + B) and check for error

@interface <# class name #> : <# superclass #>

@end